# How to loop parameter "a" in Henon map?

Tags: dynamical-systems, mathematical-physics, python

I am trying to draw a Henon map (Henon attractor) based on the Python 3 code in this link https://blbadger.github.io/henon-map.html. The different point is that links fixes a=1.4, b=0.3. I want to draw a figure with parameter "a" in the range (0,1.4) rather than a fix a=1.4.

I modified the code as follows. Even though there is no error, I received nothing. Could anyone please let me know what should I do to get the figure of Henon attractor? Thanks!

````
def henon_attractor(x, y, a, b=0.3):
  for a in range(0, 1.4):
      x_next = 1 - a * x ** 2 + y
      y_next = b * x
      return x_next, y_next
    
  # number of iterations and array initialization
  steps = 3000
  X = np.zeros(steps + 1)
  Y = np.zeros(steps + 1)

  # initial point
  X[0], Y[0] = 0, 0

  # add points to array
  for i in range(steps):
    x_next, y_next = henon_attractor(X[i], Y[i])
    X[i+1] = x_next
    Y[i+1] = y_next
    
  plt.plot(X, Y, 'o', color='red', alpha = 0.8, markersize=2)
  plt.title('Henon attractor (b=0.3)')
  plt.xlabel('x')
  plt.ylabel('y')

  fig1 = plt.gcf()
  plt.show()
```
````

Comment: Is the indentation true to the code you ran? Note that `for a in range(0,1.4):` runs the following block for `a=0` and `a=1`, but with the return statement where it is, the result for `a=0` gets returned. However, the code will not reach that point, even with correct indentation, as the call has only 2 instead of 3 (or 4) arguments.

Comment: Thanks @LutzLehmann! I see some errors in the code now. Not just about indentation but I need to add at least one arguments (e.g parameter "a") in the call.

Comment: You need to give some more thought to "draw a figure with parameter 'a' in the range (0,1.4)", what does it mean, how should the picture look like conceptually? As mock-up/experiment, if the plots where of circles and $a$ is the radius or connected to the midpoint, what would the figure look like?

Comment: @LutzLehmann My question is just the initial step to get the figure of noisy Henon map (Figure 2 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.04385.pdf). I need to modify the range and add the noise term.

Comment: This plot makes no sense. One could as well take a discretization of a spiral to get such a plot. Or make the logistic map dynamic, $x_{k+1}=r_kx_k(1-x_k)$, $r_{k+1}=r_k+h$ with some small $h$. What the random numbers are for is also a riddle, they make the time series a little more fuzzy, and ...? And why do they both use the same random number? $y_{n+1}=x_{n+1}$ also seems to be wrong, this would put all points on the diagonal, it should be $y_{n+1}=x_n$. If you want to build on this paper, you need to do a lot of critical analysis on it.

Comment: I am confused about the term $y_{n+1} = x_{n+1}$ too. Also the parameter b. In the original paper (i.e. Henon 1976) the second equation should be $y_{n+1} = b x_n$. I guess you know this paper but any way you can find it here just in case https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-50/issue-1/A-two-dimensional-mapping-with-a-strange-attractor/cmp/1103900150.full

Comment: It does not matter much how the factor $b$ is distributed. It amounts to a rescaling of the $y$ coordinate.

Comment: I see. Anyway I see this is a published paper, so I think the authors might have some reasons when they write $y_{n+1} = x_{n+1}$ instead of $y_{n+1} = x_{n}$ http://www-sop.inria.fr/abs/teaching/centrale-FGMDA/exam_mathieu/finance/TDAFinancialTimeSeries.pdf

Comment: There are mathematicians that care to use the right word in the right place, so that every thought is expressed as unambiguous as possible. And then there are the others that still can get published, especially if they can tack on some pseudo-application to some hype topic like reading the tea leaves or some stock index.

Comment: I see your point. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Henon dynamic is, when reduced to one dimension, of order 2 with recursion formula
$$
x_{n+1}=1-ax_n^2+bx_{n-1}.
$$

The plots of the Henon attractor then are of pairs $(x_n,x_{n-1})$ (which invites the idea for 3D plots of triples $(x_n,x_{n-1},x_{n-2})$).

For $a=0$ the fixed point is at $x=\frac1{1-b}$.

The paper then makes the process "adiabatically" dynamic by slowly increasing $a$ to $1.4$, to then plot the points $(a_n,x_n)$. In a short Python script this can be achieved as follows.

```
a=np.linspace(0,1.4,50000)
b=np.linspace(0.27,0.3,4)
x = [1/(1-b)]*2
for an in a[2:]:
    x.append(1-an*x[-1]**2+b*x[-2])

x = np.asarray(x)
plt.plot(a,x,'o',ms=1)
plt.legend(b); plt.grid(); 
plt.tight_layout(); plt.show()
```

This gives the plot
[image]

This could of course also be done for each $b$ separately. Adding noise will make the plot more "stochastic", but will change little of the dynamical picture.

Comment: Thanks for the nice plot, Lutz. I'll try to add the noise term on it. Hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: I have a follow up question. Why did you write $x = [1/(1-b)]*2$ instead of $x = 1/(1-b)$ in your code?

Comment: I need 2 elements in the sequence start, it was the most simple variant to set them both to the same value. If you stay with the system formulation, you need initial values for $x$ and $y$. // Multiplying a list by an integers concatenates the given number of copies of the original list.

Comment: I got it. Thank you!